# Implementing Monitor in C using semaphore, leads to deadlock

Tags: c, semaphore, monitor

I tried to implement monitor in C using semaphore, in order to solve producer consumer problem with bounded buffer.
Following is the code which I used to implement monitor.

```
#include<semaphore.h>

int availableItemCounts;
int bufferSize;
int itemShouldBeProducedCount;
int itemShouldBeConsumedCount;
int availableItemIndex;//index of last item inserted in buffer.
char *buffer;
sem_t mutex;

typedef struct
{
    sem_t semaphore;
    int numberOfBlockedThreads;
} Condition;

Condition bufferIsFull, bufferIsEmpty;


int countCV(Condition conditionVariable)
{
    return conditionVariable.numberOfBlockedThreads;
}

void waitCV(Condition conditionVariable)
{
    conditionVariable.numberOfBlockedThreads++;
    sem_wait(&(conditionVariable.semaphore));
}

void signalCV(Condition conditionVariable)
{
    if(countCV(conditionVariable)>0)
    {
        sem_post(&(conditionVariable.semaphore));
        conditionVariable.numberOfBlockedThreads--;
    }
    else
    {
        sem_post(&mutex);
    }
}


void monitorInit(int buffSize, int itemSBPC,int itemSBCC)
{
    availableItemCounts=0;
    availableItemIndex=-1;
    bufferSize=buffSize;
    itemShouldBeProducedCount=itemSBPC;
    itemShouldBeConsumedCount=itemSBCC;
    char tempBuffer[bufferSize];
    buffer=tempBuffer;
    sem_init(&(bufferIsFull.semaphore), 0, 0);
    sem_init(&(bufferIsEmpty.semaphore), 0, 0);
    sem_init(&(mutex), 0, 1);
    bufferIsEmpty.numberOfBlockedThreads=0;
    bufferIsFull.numberOfBlockedThreads=0;
}

void monitor_Insert(char item)
{
    sem_wait(&mutex);
    if (itemShouldBeProducedCount>0)
    {
        if(availableItemCounts==bufferSize)
        {
            sem_post(&mutex);
            waitCV(bufferIsFull);
            sem_wait(&mutex);
        }
        availableItemIndex++;
        buffer[availableItemIndex]=item;
        printf("p:%lu, item: %c, at %d\n", pthread_self(), item, availableItemIndex);
        itemShouldBeProducedCount--;
        availableItemCounts++;
        signalCV(bufferIsEmpty);
    }
    else
    {
        sem_post(&mutex);
        pthread_exit(NULL);
    }

}

void monitor_Remove(char item)
{
    sem_wait(&mutex);
    if (itemShouldBeConsumedCount>0)
    {
        if(availableItemCounts==0)
        {
            sem_post(&mutex);
            waitCV(bufferIsEmpty);
            sem_wait(&mutex);
        }
        item=buffer[availableItemIndex];
        printf("c:%lu, item: %c, at %d\n", pthread_self(), item, availableItemIndex);
        availableItemIndex--;
        itemShouldBeConsumedCount--;
        availableItemCounts--;
        signalCV(bufferIsFull);

    }
    else
    {
        sem_post(&mutex);
        pthread_exit(NULL);
    }
}
```

and this is my main file (main function):

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<pthread.h>
#include<semaphore.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include "Monitor.h"

void *produce(void *index);
void *consume(void *index);

int itemShouldBeProducedCount;//total number of items that should be produced.
int itemShouldBeConsumedCount;//total number of items that should be consumed.
int bufferSize;


int main(int argc, char **argv)
{

    int index;
    int error;
    int producerCount=atoi( argv[4]);
    int consumerCount=atoi( argv[6]);

    itemShouldBeProducedCount=atoi( argv[8]);
    itemShouldBeConsumedCount=itemShouldBeProducedCount;
    bufferSize=atoi( argv[2]);

    monitorInit(bufferSize,itemShouldBeProducedCount,itemShouldBeConsumedCount);

    sem_init(&(bufferIsFull.semaphore), 0, 0);
    sem_init(&(bufferIsEmpty.semaphore), 0, 0);

    printf("Producer Count:%d\n", producerCount);
    printf("Consumer Count:%d\n", consumerCount);
    printf("Buffer size Count:%d\n", bufferSize);
    printf("Items should be produced:%d\n", itemShouldBeProducedCount);
    printf("Items should be consumed:%d\n", itemShouldBeConsumedCount);

    monitorInit(bufferSize,itemShouldBeProducedCount,itemShouldBeConsumedCount);

    pthread_t producerThreads[ producerCount ];
    pthread_t consumerThreads[ consumerCount ];

    for( index = 0; index < producerCount; index++ )
    {
        printf("In main: creating producer thread %d\n", index);
        error = pthread_create( &producerThreads[index], NULL, produce, &index );

    }

    for( index = 0; index < consumerCount; index++ )
    {
        printf("In main: creating consumer thread %d\n", index);
        error = pthread_create( &consumerThreads[index], NULL, consume, &index );

    }


    // wait for each producer thread to complete
    for( index = 0; index < producerCount; ++index )
    {
        // block until thread 'index' completes
        pthread_join( producerThreads[ index ], NULL );
        printf( "In main: producer thread %d has completed\n", index );
    }

    // wait for each consumer thread to complete
    for( index = 0; index < consumerCount; ++index )
    {
        // block until thread 'index' completes
        pthread_join( consumerThreads[ index ], NULL );
        printf( "In main: consumer thread %d has completed\n", index );
    }

    sem_destroy(&(bufferIsFull.semaphore));
    sem_destroy(&(bufferIsEmpty.semaphore));

    return 0;
}

void *produce(void *threaID)
{
    unsigned char item;
    while(1)
    {
        item= (unsigned char) (rand() % 256);//generating an item
        monitor_Insert(item);
    }
    return NULL;
}

void *consume(void *threaID)
{
    while(1)
    {
        char item;
        monitor_Remove(item);

    }
    return NULL;
}
```

but unfortunately it leads to deadlock. I checked the processes and I found out that all the producers and consumers wait on mutex. What should I do?

Comment: Are you sure that neither `producerCount` or `consumerCount' is zero?  Have you stepped into the code with a debugger?

Comment: I'm sure that it generates 10 producers and 10 consumers, and all of them on some point in the program are blocked, while they are waiting for releasing semaphore mutex.

Comment: Can you ever pass a semaphore by value?

Comment: Also since you pass Condition by value, the original Condition never changes and numberOfBlockedThreads stays at zero, so you might just as well remove it and all the corresponding branches.  If you pass Condition by pointer, as you should, then you have a race condition on numberOfBlockedThreads and you need to make it atomic. Why do you need numberOfBlockedThreads at all?

Comment: Condition variables are not passed by value. They've been defined as global. Also I checked my program and I'm sure that all threads waits on mutex. My professor recommended me to use that to know how many threads are waiting on each condition variables. I told her that is useless, but she recommended me again.

Answer (score 0):

Add `sem_post(&mutex);` to the end of your instert and remove functions.  There's one pathway through each that leads to more `sem_wait` calls than `sem_post`.

EDIT: You still have a design flaw after fixing this bug.  I recommend that you place each of the variables that must be protected into a struct and add the mutex to that, then acquire that lock before reading/writing any of those variables and release the lock as soon as your done. This is an all or nothing under one lock approach.

Comment: I did so, but it led to inconsistent access to the buffer.

Comment: Well that's a different bug.  Your not caught in a deadlock anymore.

Comment: So what is the point of using a monitor which leads to inconsistent access to shared data, while we know that monitor is a mechanism which is used for preventing such inconsistent data accesses?

Comment: According to [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monitor_(synchronization)), a monitor has one mutex and a number of condition variables.  It doesn't mention waiting on any additional semaphores.

Comment: Yes, the monitor in its concept is so, but because I have to use a bounded buffer, I need to check number of items which are inserted into buffer, so I should check two variables, which both of them are shared variables. If I don't use mutex, threads can write/read on/from negative indices, so it leads to segmentation fault.

Comment: I think we've established that the deadlock with all threads waiting on a mutex, was the result of unequal `sem_post` and `sem_wait` calls.  What's left, seems to be another problem entirely.

Comment: There exists the same number of corresponding sem_waits and sem_posts.